# C++) I don't know the fast algorithm to compare coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, compare

Up to 100,000 coordinates are entered. Only coordinates corresponding to specific conditions should be output. If there are coordinates with larger x values ​​and smaller y values ​​than each coordinate, the corresponding coordinates are excluded from the output list.

My English is not good, so I'm giving some examples.

[input]
First enter the number of coordinates N to be input.
and enter the coordinates.

[output]
The coordinate numbers corresponding to the condition are output in ascending order.

```
[input example]

6
1 3
6 6
7 3
8 2
8 6
2 1
```

```
[output example]

4
5
6
```

[coordinates image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y0KM.png)

The following problem was solved with a simple loop, but a timeout occurs when 100,000 values ​​are entered. I don't know which algorithm to use.

I also attach the C++ source code I wrote.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    bool* visible = new bool[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)visible[i] = true;
    
    vector<pair<int,pair<int, int>>> v;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        v.push_back(make_pair(i,make_pair(a, b)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (visible[i] == false)
            continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {
            if (visible[i] == true &&visible[j]==true && v[i].second.first < v[j].second.first && v[i].second.second > v[j].second.second) {
                visible[i] = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (visible[i] == true && visible[j] == true && v[i].second.first > v[j].second.first && v[i].second.second < v[j].second.second) {
                visible[j] = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (visible[i] == true)
            cout << v[i].first + 1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown your code so why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Can you share an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why are p1, p10, p2, p6, and p7 the correct points? What are the criteria?

Comment: Make a [mcve] please.

Comment: you axis have no labels. What is `x` and what is `y` in the image?

Comment: Thank you guys. 
I modified the contents and attached an example of input and output and my source code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem about dominating points set.

Sort points by X value (Y is secondary key in case of X equality)

Assign the first point (with the largest X) to `Big` variable and add it to the result

Walk through array. If you meet point that is not dominated by `Big` - assign it to `Big` and add it to the result

Comment: I modified the contents and attached an example of input and output and my source code.

Comment: I described fast approach. After sorting you scan array in backward direction, at first choose p5, then p4 (after comparison with p5), the compare p3 and p2 with p4 and omit them, then choose p6 and omit p1.

Answer (score 0):

The proper terms for your problem are Pareto front(ier), ND-tree, KD-tree, non-dominance problem.

There are libraries for that e.g.
https://github.com/alandefreitas/pareto-front

However it 2 dims it is a simple task.
You have to sort your points by one of the coordinates. And then scan from the best one to the worst and accepts only if the other coordinate is not dominated by previously acquired point. And it will give you `O(n log(n))` that is the best possible in general case for such tasks.

Comment: "_sort your points by one of the coordinates_" - If you mean sorting on only `x` or `y` it would make the comparison function not fulfilling the strict weak ordering requirement (`if(not pos1 < pos2 && not pos2 < pos1)` then `pos1` and `pos2` are equal) so I'd not use that comparison function with `std::sort`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `if (not a < b && not b < a)`, then `a` and `b` are *equivalent* with respect to the comparison being made. `a` and `b` are not necessarily *equal*. It doesn't break the strict weak ordering requirement.

Comment: @Kevin Hmm, yeah, you are probably correct when it comes to sorting.

Comment: I modified the contents and attached an example of input and output and my source code.